# How to stop gnome-power-manager from changing the global backlight setting?

Tags: brightness, gnome-power-manager, backlight

After installing Ubuntu on my ThinkPad T510, the GDM screen and GNOME session would always start at 100% brightness.

I quickly found out, that this can be controlled via `gnome-power-preferences`, but I'd like to have GDM and the GNOME session follow the global backlight setting (ie., when I set it during POST, GRUB, GDM, a GNOME session, or on a TTY, I expect it not to automatically change).

So, how can I make gnome-power-manager stop automatically changing my backlight level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems this can only be disabled by editing a gconf setting using `gconf-editor` or the command line tool `gconftool-2` (easier). As GDM is run by a special user (`gdm`), you got to disable it for the desktop user and that special user:

Run the following from a gnome-terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean  "/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/enable" false
```

This will deactivate the backlight control for your user. Now type:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set --type boolean  "/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/enable" false
```

This will deactivate the backlight control for the user that controls the GDM screen.

You should now no longer see automatic backlight level changes.

---

In Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot this changed to:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-ac false
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery false
```

Still not sure how to disable it for the login screen.

Comment: This command for ubuntu oneiric doesn't work.. can you correct it?

Comment: I think is `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery false`

Comment: Is the section about GDM's user still accurate (given that we're not on LightDM)? Edit: I see the revised section below now.

Comment: Not sure about GDM in 11.10. This should be tested with a fresh install, but I'm low on disk space on the device where I saw this happening.

Comment: Even after running the 11.10 commands here, it keeps maxing out the backlight every few seconds if I reduce it (on AC). Any idea why?

Comment: @l0b0 If you are using the binary Nvidia driver, then that's likely the culprit. Try the solutions to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74376/brightness-control-problem-on-sony-vaio-with-nvidia-gt-320m).

Comment: @htorque: Nope, don't need any proprietary driver for the Samsung 900X3A.