# Thinkpad W510 with default graphics drivers shows weird brightness issues

Tags: 10.10, thinkpad, brightness

Hey guys, I am currently running 10.10 - 32 bit on a new Thinkpad W510 with nVidia Quadro FX 880M graphics card. I am running with the default graphics drivers that installed with ubuntu install.

My problem is that when I am logging in the screen acts normally as far as birghtness is concerned. I can increase/decrease brightness with Fn keys. But few seconds after I log in  screen goes pitch dark. Hitting Fn+Home flickers the screen to all the way bright, then all the way dark. This behavior continues until I reach maximum brightness, in which case the screen stays all the way bright, for a few more seconds and then again goes dark if there is no activity & the cycle continues.

Have you guys faced any of these issues? If so any pointers on how to resolve it. I am not alone, on ubuntu forum I saw another person having the same issue - [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10550779) but no solution.

Please help!

**UPDATE**

I followed the instructions that htorque mentions in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30088/thinkpad-w510-with-default-graphics-drivers-shows-weird-brightness-issues) and it worked.

**UPDATE 2**

After a while the issues cropped again. This time I bit the bullet and installed the nVidia's official graphics drivers (via System > Admnistration > Additional Drivers) and the issue seems to have gone. The UI seems more snappier as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to get the run dialog → type `gnome-power- preferences` and click on *Run*
- On the `On AC Power` tab there is an option *Dim display when idle* that does exactly what it says → untick it and click on *Make Default*:

  [image]
- On the `On Battery Power` tab there is above mentioned option and another one (*Reduce backlight brightness*) for automatically reducing backlight brightness when on battery → untick both and click on *Make Default*:

  [image]

---

There's another thing that was getting on my nerves with my ThinkPad T510: different backlight levels for GDM and session → read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18603/how-to-stop-gnome-power-manager-from-changing-the-global-backlight-setting) to find out how to completely stop gnome-power-manager from manipulating the backlight brightness.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into this now. Will report back with update.