# Installing nVidia drivers for Quadro FX 880M on 10.10 caused shutdown/startup issues

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, graphics, shutdown, documentation

So I was facing weird graphics drivers issues due to the [default nouveau drivers that came installed with Ubuntu 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30088/thinkpad-w510-with-default-graphics-drivers-shows-weird-brightness-issues) hence I installed the latest nVidia graphics drivers & the weird graphics issues stopped happening. So far so good, but when I tried to shut down the laptop it got stuck at the window with text

```
15, shutting down...
modem-manager: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
init: Disconnected from system us
init: dbus main process (1107) killed by TERM signal
```

And this happens .everytime.without.fail. I tried updating the kernel and any/all drivers through update manager but it still happens. Not only this even the startup screen is totally screwed up. It just displays Ubuntu 10.10 in text with 3 dots. But that is acceptable. To power cycle down the laptop each and everytime for shutdown is not. Same goes for when I try to restart.

Interesting thing is if I try to shutdown the laptop when I am on the login screen it does so without any problems.

I googled & many people seem to face the same issue but I couldn't find any silver bullet hoping to find one here.

Comment: definitely a driver issue, the reason it doesn't evidence itself on the login screen is that it's still using the old plymouth driver(generic) and not the REAL driver for whatever.  file a bug with the driver ppl for your particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I figured out to resolve this. I can't believe it is so simple. Just went to this page on Ubuntu Wiki - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia
and then followed the recommended steps for Ubuntu 10.10 & we are all set. Just pasting here steps for reference -

> Version 96.43.18 is broken ,Go to
>   System->Administration->Software
>   sources then go to the update's
>   tab--tick proposed update
>   sources--close & refesh. please follow
>   this link for more infomantion
>   http://joeslifewithubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/12/update-on-nvidia-96-driver-with-ubuntu.html